# Data scraping & NLP?

Tags: python, nlp, csv, scraping

I'm scraping data from Bing search results for (non-commercial purposes, of course) on Python using BeautifulSoup. I've entered an Indian dessert name, called 'rasmalai' as the word that I am focusing on. The code I'm using returns the title and a description of the web page. I've also extracted the links for the results. Here is the code I used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib, urllib2

def bing_search(query):
    address = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=%s" % (urllib.quote_plus(query))

    getRequest = urllib2.Request(address, None, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36'})

    urlfile = urllib2.urlopen(getRequest)
    htmlResult = urlfile.read(200000)
    urlfile.close()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlResult)

    [s.extract() for s in soup('span')]
    #unwantedTags = ['a', 'strong', 'cite']
    #for tag in unwatedTags:
        #for match in soup.findAll(tag):
           # match.replaceWithChildren()

    results = soup.findAll('li', {"class" : "b_algo" })
    for result in results: 
        print "# TITLE: " + str(result.find('h2')).replace(" ", " ") + "\n#"
        print "# DESCRIPTION: " + str(result.find('p')).replace(" ", " ")
        print "# ___________________________________________________________\n#"

    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = bing_search('rasmalai')
```

Now that I have the links, web page title, and a short description, I want to extract keywords using NLP. In the end, I'd like to produce a CSV file with the dish name and associated keywords. Could someone guide me to some resources on how to do this part?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean by extracting keywords using NLP?
Do you want to produce keywords based on description?

Comment: @DanielChepenko yes, that's exactly what I mean!

Comment: http://blog.kbresearch.nl/2016/01/11/from-keyword-search-to-concept-mining/
Take a look at this post

Answer (score 2):

**NLTK**

A great starting point for keyword extraction is the NLTK (natural language toolkit) library.  To extract keywords, you probably need to tokenize your data, breaking each word out into a token, and ignore the most common or unimportant words known as "stopwords".  Assuming you're searching for keywords across a large number of query results, identify the most important terms in each document using TF-IDF ([term frequency–inverse document frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)).  There are tools and tutorials for this in the [NLTK documentation](https://www.nltk.org/book/).  Sort the resulting token-scores, choose the highest scoring tokens, and these are a good start at your keywords.